# Java lambda: combine doSomething() and removeIf() in one iteration

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-stream

I want to filter some elements and call `stop()` function, and then remove them. Here is the sample code:

```
items.stream().filter(x -> x.children.isEmpty()).forEach(x::stop);
items.removeIf(x -> x.children.isEmpty());
```

Can we combine these two iterations into one in Java Stream style?

Just like do something then `removeif()` in one iteration.

Comment: Not really, you can't change `items` WHILE you are "streaming" it. If at all, you could replace the method reference to stop with a lambda that STOPS and remembers the corresponding items in another list. And then do a removeAll() in the end. See https://www.baeldung.com/java-use-remove-item-stream for example.

Comment: You can not combine them “in Java Stream style” but you can in “Java Collection removeIf style”, `items.removeIf(x -> { if(x.children.isEmpty()) { x.stop(); return true } return false; });`

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev, we can do it doesn't mean we should do it. I can't imagine how my colleague will feel if I write a stateful Predicate. Also I don't know why there are so many questions asking for doing multiple thing in one stream, which violate what stream is designed for. Even we can do so, code are usually less readable.

Comment: The OP asked to _combine these two iterations into one in Java Stream style_ and the Holger comment was exactly this. I've just suggested to answer because is the best answer till now. No `forEach`, no more than one iteration. I admit that the multiple operations on a stream is not what the streams are meant for but the question is just this.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code already entails side effects via `forEach()`, adding more side effects will not make it cleaner.

Instead of using `peek()` or stateful `filter()`, I'd rather rewrite your code this way.

```
Map<Boolean, List<Item>> itemByIsEmpty = items.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(x -> x.getChildren().isEmpty()));
        
itemByIsEmpty.get(true).forEach(Item::stop);        
List<Item> nonEmpty = itemByIsEmpty.get(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, which will NOT work?

```
for(Item i : items) {
  if(i.children.isEmpty()) {
    i.stop();
    items.remove(i); // This will fail!
  }
}
```

The solution is as always to build a new list (I assume that it's a list, but the idea is the same regardless of the collection):

```
List<Item> unstopped = new ArrayList<>();
for(Item i : items) {
  if(i.children.isEmpty()) {
    i.stop();
  } else {
    unstopped.add(i);
  }
}
```

And if you don't need to use a stream, might do just fine. It's certainly not hard to read what's going on.

Can we translate this to a lambda? Yes, but I don't like it, because well, the above code was easy to read, and this is not. You need to either create a filter with side effects, so that it returns true if it was not empty, and thus did not have to stop, or use forEach immediately.

```
// I do not recommend this, it's there for completion:
List<Items> unstopped = items.stream()
  .filter(i -> {
    if(i.children.isEmpty()) {
      i.stop() // side effect
      return false; // we're not keeping these
    } else {
      return true; // we're keeping the non-empty ones
    })
  .collect(toList());
```

But this *looks* bad, which is a hint that there's something wrong with the code. I would immensely prefer the older iteration based approach. Just try to give that Predicate we used a name. It's... hard.

The other way is to just use forEach immediately:

```
List<Item> unstopped = new ArrayList<>();
items.stream().forEach(i -> {
  if(i.children.isEmpty()) {
      i.stop()     
    } else {
      unstopped.add(i)
    })
  });
```

And that works. And it's kind of honest. But it's still just the same old loop-based way of doing it.

You might get away with using teeing, but it's still iffy. https://dzone.com/articles/java-12-the-teeing-collector

Or you could do what @Alexander Ivanchenko suggested, which works just fine. But I would ask myself this question first:

"Do I really need to use streams? Since I'm dealing with stateful side effects anyway, what's wrong with using the other syntax that handles that sort of thing really well instead?"

If the answer is that yes you need to use a stream, then that's fine. But it might be the wrong hammer for the nail.

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about it differently.
Use a second collection for this purpose.
You don't even need the `Stream` API

```
List<X> items = ...
Set<X> itemsToBeStopped = new HashSet<>(items);

items.removeIf(x -> x.children.isEmpty());
itemsToBeStopped.removeAll(items);

itemsToBeStopped.forEach(x::stop);
```

Just make sure your `equals` and `hashcode` methods are overridden properly

Comment: Method `removeAll()` iterates over the list and invokes `contains()` for every element on a collection that was passed as an argument. If this collection also happens to be a list, then the method will perform in **O(n^2)** time. Do you really consider it to be a better option in comparison to any other snippet of code listed on this page?

Comment: What do you mean by better @AlexanderIvanchenko ? Big O notation is only relevant if you expect your algorithm to be able to scale. Otherwise, with small amounts of data, it usually does not matter at all. Clarity over performance. The code here is clear to understand.

Comment: The time complexity issue could be easily fixed by changing `List<X> itemsToBeStopped = new ArrayList<>(items);` to `Set<X> itemsToBeStopped = new HashSet<>(items);` The clarity wouldn’t suffer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `peek()`:

```
items = items.stream()
  .peek(i -> { if (i.children.isEmpty()) i.stop();})
  .filter(i -> !i.children.isEmpty())
  .collect(toList());
```

Comment: If anyone has any doubts about using `peek()`, I challenge them to write a test that proves it doesn't work and post it here. I've successfully used peek() in production code for years and my deployments have been fault free for years.

Comment: *write a test that proves it doesn't work* - So any test will do?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko what do you mean?

Comment: Ok, that's a quote from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects): *side-effects of behavioral parameters may not always be executed when the stream implementation can optimize away the execution of behavioral parameters without affecting the result of the computation*.

Comment: And that's a valid stream with `peek()` which doesn't print anything (*as documentation warns it'll not get executed*): `IntStream.of(1,2,3,4,5).map(i->i<<1).peek(System.out::println).count();` Only if you stick `filter()`, `takeWhile()`, `dropWhile()` or `limit()` in the stream, it will be galvanized into action.

Comment: *what do you mean?* - I've meant are there'any specific requirement for the example of broken `peek()` you were asking for? I.e. any arbitrary example will do, or challenge is to break the code you've written?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko the doc says peek is for debugging and warns against using peek for side effects/mutation, but the fact is it works just fine. Yes, try to break my code! (other than having stop() throw runtime exceptions etc that would break any code). ie I challenge anyone to show why this wouldn't work. Look at the implementation of peek and you'll see it's simple and suited for the purpose as used in my code. I don't care about future changes in JRE, because if that happens my copious test suite will fail and I'll find another way, but YAGNI applies here.

Comment: @alex LOL. Yes I forgot to add a collector (I only thumbed it in on the sofa). Added now, but the remaining discussion about peek still stands.

Comment: Now, this code is fine, and I don't expect it to be broken anyhow. In regard to the continuation of discussion, I don't think that I'm capable to challenge your knowledge and experience.

Comment: You don’t know what `stop()` does. If it adds an element to `children`, this solution will break. Yes, that’s an unlikely corner case, but none of the other answers has this problem. So, the question is not, does this `peek` based approach happen to do the desired thing in this specific case, the question should be, *is there an actual reason to shoehorn a bad solution, knowingly using a discouraged coding style, known to potentially break if requirements change, to a Q&A that does already have better solutions without these flaws?*

Comment: @holger because it's simple, easy to understand, less code and unit testing will discover any problems (which I'm  confident there won't be - suggesting `stop()` will add items is drawing a very long bow). There's theory and there's the practicality of what works.

Comment: Speaking of theory and reality, what makes you believe that the OP (or anyone who will copy your code) has unit tests? Your code is not “less code” than [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71795626/2711488), not to speak of [this one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71795427/71802256?noredirect=1#comment126874632_71795427). In fact, it’s not even shorter nor simpler than a straight-forward loop. Seeing your first comment, I get the impression, you only posted this because you wanted this discussion, rather than helping the questioner.